# Path constant in PHP

Tags: php, constants

I have different classes and a configuration file in my PHP Application. The classes sits inside a single directory. My application structure is as follows

```
/ApplicationName
    /administrator
         adminFiles.php
         someMoreAdmingFiles.php
         anotherAdminFiles.php
         /resources
             /config
                 config.php
             /library
                 /class
                     class.user.php
                     class.acl.php
                 /models
             /logs
             /templates
    /contents
        /uploads
    /css
    /img
    /css
```

i would like to create path CONSTANTS in config.php, now i used the following code to create a path constant for class.user.php

```
define('USERCLASS_PATH',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/ApplicationName/administrator/resources/library/class/class.user.php');
```

Above CONSTANT generates the following string.

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ApplicationName/administrator/resources/library/class/class.user.php
```

is there any better way for achieving this?

Comment: You shouldn't create constants for each and every class. Just create a path to where your class files folder is. Or better yet, use something like autoloading to load on demand

Comment: what is autoloading to load on demand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use something in the lines of:

```
define("PATH_ROOT", realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

Comment: i am confused on how to use that code? could you please help explaining like if i have to attach class.users.php from class directory in adminFiles.php where do i place the code?

Comment: You should define path constants in your application. You should make one to find your classes in, but not the classes themselves. You should use an autoloader to use these path constants and load classes dynamically. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php